# Create a random generator for a range [min, max] given a 0/1 random generator

Tags: random

Given a random generator, which generate 0 or 1 with the same probability, how to create a random generator `int generateRandom(int min, int max)`which generate a random number with he same probability in a range [min, max]?

If this function would be called multiple times with arbitrary min and max, how to optimize it to improve the time efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python solution

```
import math
import random

def power_two(n):
    return int(math.log(n, 2))

def generate_random(min_, max_):
    p2 = power_two(max_ - min_) + 1
    while True:
        n = 0
        for i in xrange(p2):
            n <<= 1
            if random.randint(0, 1):
                n += 1
        if n <= max_ - min_:
            return n + min_
```

First it calculates how many bits it needs with `power_two`, then it generates a number bit by bit, and only if it is in the `0 <= n <= max - min` range it returns `n + min_`

Comment: Assume `max=6` and `min=0`, your solution will never set the highest order bit to 1, easily fixed though. I'd think describing the algorithm makes more sense than an implementation though.

Comment: @Voo There I added an explanation and fixed the off by one error

Answer (score -2):

Can I just clarify what you are trying to optimise? There are at least three layers of code here:
1: some kind of app, calling item 2:
2: int generateRandom(int min, int max), calling item 3:
3: some random generator that generates 0 or 1
Are you trying to make 2 run very fast or make 3 run very fast?

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment. Furthermore I don't think layers of code are even relevant here, he's just trying to figure out how to generate a truly random number between any two arbitrary numbers, with just a function that returns just a single bit.